# Why judge, it makes no sense

Tags: philosophy-of-mind

what I mean by this is, why should I do that project or why should I just do anything other than the natural laws of human life?

Why should you care what I wear or like if it does not directly hurt any or all of who you are?

But the sense in no sense is that nothing really matters but also is very important. It is how you interpret it if you want to play sports for fun or college, someone will judge you for not being good at something that THEY are serious about but you aren't taking it seriously.

So my actual thought is why judge without knowledge of the person, place, or situation?

Comment: This is either a psychology question or pushing your own philosophy.

Comment: Yes. This is the direction of wisdom : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matthew_5:39. Also Matt 7:1-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging helps you survive: you are predicting a behavior. Even if you are wrong, your survival probabilities enhance.

For example: you've heard lions are dangerous. So, you see one, and jou judge it *to be dangerous*, and so, you protect yourself. Even if they are harmless, you survive.

But if you don't, you think like "we should not judge anyone or anything", and you expect to know personally every lion before you judge it. Bam! you are dead at the first encounter. You don't even survive to know you were wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> Any idea is a universalization, and universalizing is a property of
> thinking. To universalize something means to think.

-Georg Wilhelm Friedrich Hegel [from: *Elements of the Philosophy of Right*]

And: if you want to be convinced to think, then you're already thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Judgement is necessary because certain actions lead to pain and suffering. Given the judgement of pain and suffering, a path is developed to reduce or remove pain and suffering. If you are innocent like a child or are a child then it is the responsibility of father , mother , government, societies to guide you on the right path. This guidance is born out of love and compassion. But it is your choice to follow the path. Choice is given to every form of life. Choice involves judgement. You do not exist in isolation. You may or may not judge others but others have the right to judge you.